# forEach doesn't work with fs in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

I have a small function here but it doesn't work.

```
function update_counter() { 
  const channels = fs.readFileSync('./channels.json', {"encoding": "utf-8"}); //doesn't work
    channel_count_template.channel_count = 0
    channels.forEach(channel => {    
        channel_count_template.channel_count += 3000; 
        fs.writeFileSync("channels-count.json", JSON.stringify(channel_count_template, null, 2)); 
    })
}
```

With require, it works, but I have to update the file every time the function gets executed.
For a better explanation here is the channels.json file:

```
[
  {
    "channel": [
      "438766794747896789"
    ],
    "info": {
      "cooldown": 3000
    }
  },
  {
    "channel": [
      "izulköio"
    ],
    "info": {
      "cooldown": 6000
    }
  }
]
```

Thanks for helping me ;)

Comment: This time it was immediately obvious for me what's wrong, but next time please don't just write "doesn't work", how are we supposed to know what happened? What doesn't work, and _in what way_ did it not work: what did you expect to happen and what happened instead, and did you debug your code to trace back the unexpected result or error to its source? These are the questions that would need to be answered to be able to properly help you.

Comment: In this case, I'd expect to see something like "I am getting the error `channels.forEach is not a function` on this line, here is the error stack: (xxx) - Logging the channels variable shows me this (xxx)"

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to parse the JSON string in the file using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
const json = fs.readFileSync('./channels.json', {"encoding": "utf-8"});
const channels = JSON.parse(json)
```

Without this, you had a string (not an array) in the variable, and a string doesn't have any `forEach` method.

Comment: thanks ;) And sorry for the bad explanation. If I have more questions in the future i'll describe it a little bit more ;xD